# How to make a message box pop up showing all the values that match a search in a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of items that looks like this in Excel:

[image: List of Items]

This list then is used as a reference for my tables in other multiple Excel sheets and files:

[image: Table in multiple sheets]

The formula in Col B is: (If A in list, "Delete", "Keep").
I have built a macro that will loop over col B and get rid of the whole row if there's `Delete` as value. so in this example row number 5 will be deleted if I click on the blue button.

Here is my code for that (works for all worksheets in the workbook):

```
Option Explicit
Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = Last To 1 Step -1
                if (.Cells(i, "B").Value) = "Delete" Then
                    .Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Now what I need is an additional rows of vba code that will allow Excel to go through all worksheets in the workbook and pop up the message box showing what records match the list in the first image. If there is no match, then show "No records found".

Below is the framework of the code that I tried, but I couldn't seem to find the right way to do it. I also put this as a separate macro module so I can click on this first before I delete the rows that match the list.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Range ="List" Then
         MsgBox ""
   Else MsgBox "No match found."
   End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Try creating a string (`Public z as String`) and then loop to capture such that `z = z & ", " & ws.Cells(i,1).Value` and output `MsgBox "language" & z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will put my comment as an answer, since reading code from there is awful:

```
Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, Last As Long, x as long, z as string
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
            if (.Cells(i, "B").Value) = "Delete" Then
                z = z & ", " & .Cells(i,1).Value
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
Next ws
If x > 0 then
    MsgBox "The following names will be deleted: " & z
    Application.Run "WorksheetLoop" 'Will run the delete code after names are found
Else
    MsgBox "No match found."
End If
```

Comment: Hi @Cyril, thanks for the answer! can you explain about the logic for x and z please? Other than that it works perfectly well! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Just one more thing, how to modify the above code if my data starts at row 4 (C4) instead of row 1?

Comment: I tried changing `B` in your code to `C` and it doesn't work.